# Getting users to not be able to navigate out of document library sight

Tags: sharepoint-online

Users should be able to add/view documents.

Users should not have the ability to navigate away from the SharePoint documents list.  As in they should not have any ability to navigate to other areas of SharePoint.

An option I was thinking of was to remove/disable the links highlighted by the red box in the picture below. Any ideas on how to approach this?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to restrict users from accessing SharePoint site other than the document library, consider using custom unique permission to grant the users direct access to this library.

This is what users can see when we put a document library web part on a modern page. It hides several buttons on the menu, but users still have access to the full menu in the library by clicking “See all”.

[image]

As far as I know, we cannot hide the buttons from the menu since modern experience doesn’t accept customization.

- Users need **View Application Pages** permission to access the **All Items** view of the document library, which will give them access to
  the **Switch view options**.

[image]

- To hide **Power Apps** and **Power Automate** buttons from the menu, you need
  to disable these features on the site level.

In conclusion, even users with **View Only** permission have access to the **Switch view options**, **Filters**, **Details** and **Power Automated** buttons with full functions enabled in this site.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea: Create a page with a webpart document viewer and have that be the primary page users access. I'm not sure it removes the 'share' ability. A power user might still find their way into the real document library though. Or an inept user might keep going to the real document library by using an old link or favorite.

You should also look into custom permission levels. And site settings to remove some options.